# Angular cache options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular and wanted to implement the cache in it. I have found few after Google http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html

http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/

Can anyone suggest which is the best cache for angular. My app is a kind of ticketing system and i need to cache many drop-down list value and and view data. 
i need to cache the object of the list (not html). There are few list which will change very rarely and some are that can change after a day or two. if i can cache the $http call in local storage , it would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking to cache data models for your drop-down list / view data OR if you need to cache HTML of the drop-down?

Comment: i need to cache the object of the list (not html). There are few list which will change very rarely and some are that can change after a day or two. 
if i can cache the $http call in local storage , it would be great.

Comment: If your goal is to save the network request, then yes, localStorage w/cookie fallback will probably be your best bet, and that module you linked to is fine. You could also look at optimizing the backend and doing the caching there, and just making sure the network request is fast.

Comment: @aet canu guide which one is good to use of above or anyone else ?

Comment: I believe this comment answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190745/1974681

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need a **persistent cache** then you may consider simply using the built-in AngularJS $[cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory).

To obtain cache persistence you would need look at using local storage. There are a number of options available however [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) is the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a custom cache in the service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190745/1974681

With this approach when you reload your app, the caché is refreshed too.

You could use localStorage or sessionStorage. In that case the cache will not be refreshed on app reload (https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/).

> localStorage and sessionStorage accomplish the exact same thing and have the same API, but with sessionStorage the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed, while with localStorage the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.

As easy as:

```js
const data = {hello: 'world'};
sessionStorage.setItem('KEY', JSON.stringify(data));

sessionStorage.getItem('KEY'); // {hello: 'world'}
```