# How to correctly retrieve and cache data in Angular service

Tags: angular

Frequently, in angular app, i have some service, which need to retreive some data through http request and share it to consumers through BehaviorSubject. It have implementation like this:

```
class Service { 

  private data = new BehaviorSubject();

  getData() {
    if (!this.data.getValue()) {
      anyHttpCall().subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
    }

    return this.data.asObservable();
  } 
}
```

The main priblem of this approach is that when some components of application will call getData() at the same time when there is no value yet, it will trigger multiple http calls and data emits, so i found 2 ways to prevent it:

1)Store boolean variable which says about request status

```
class Service { 

  private data = new BehaviorSubject();   

  private pendingResult = false;

  getData() {
    if (!this.data.value && !this.pendingResult) {
      this.pendingResult = true;
      anyHttpCall().subscribe(res =>   {
        this.data.next(res);
        this.pendingResult = false;
      }
    }

    return this.data.asObservable();
  } 
}
```

2)Fetch data in service constructor

```
class Service { 

  private data = new BehaviorSubject();  

  constructor() {
    anyHttpCall().subscribe(resthis.data.next(res));
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data.asObservable();
  } 
}
```

So which of this or another approaches is the best and why

Comment: Have you looked at the NgRx library? It handles state management, data sharing, and component communication: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md

Answer (score 7):

The best way is using rxjs **shareReplay**. This operator returns an Observable that shares a single subscription to the underlying source. In other words, turns our observable hot.

```js
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;
class Service { 

  private _data$: Observable<YourType>;

  get data(): Observable<YourType> {
    if (!this._data$) {
      this._data$ = anyHttpCall()
        .pipe(shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: CACHE_SIZE })
      );
    }
    return this._data$;
  }
}
```

The **bufferSize** determines the maximum element count of the replay buffer, that is the number of elements that are cached and replayed for every subscriber.

This post explains this very good: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html

Answer (score 0):

What about initializing a stream in the constructor that is made hot by an initial call to `getData`? Then the first result is cached in the `ReplaySubject`

```
class Service {

  private init = new Subject();

  private data = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor() {
    this.init.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(() => anyHttpCall())
    )
    .subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));   
  }

  getData() {
    this.init.next();

    return this.data.asObservable();   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about your options:

1) Should work but as for me it requires a lot of code written by hand.

2) Imagine user won't call `getData` method but you have already sent redundant request.

---

There is a very convenient operator `shareReplay` that will help you make your cold observable hot.

```typescript
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';


export class Service {
  private cache$: Observable<any>;
  ...
  getData() {
    if (!this.cache$) {
      this.cache$ = this.anyHttpCall().pipe(
        shareReplay(1)
      );
    }

    return this.cache$;
  }
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/9MQLn3FAWOkJozC7klVL?open=app%2Fservice.ts)**